# How do I convert .getHours, .getMinutes, and date to a specific format? The needed format is 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a specific format when using javascript date methods. I need all single digit numbers to display with zeros in front of them and it currently just shows the single digit.

Currently, I am using an array to get the required results but it is quite lengthy.

```js
const today = new Date();
    let month = new Array();
        month[0] = '01';
        month[1] = '02';
        month[2] = '03';
        month[3] = '04';
        month[4] = '05';
        month[5] = '06';
        month[6] = '07';
        month[7] = '08';
        month[8] = '09';
const date = today.getFullYear()+''+month[today.getMonth()]+''+day[today.getDate()];
    const time = hour[today.getHours()] + ":" + minute[today.getMinutes()];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is a String in that format what you need, try this method.

```js
function getStringDateTime(date) {
  var a = date.getFullYear();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = date.getDate();
  var h = date.getHours();
  var mi = date.getMinutes();
  var strDate = a + (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d + ' ' +
    (h < 10 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (mi < 10 ? '0' + mi : mi);

  return strDate;
}

console.log(getStringDateTime(new Date()))
```

Comment: @NikoKovacevic sorry, I'd fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to format and manipulate dates, but if you absolutely cannot use a third-party package, then something like the following should help:

```
const fmtDate = (date) => {
  const y = date.getFullYear();
  const m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const d = date.getDay();
  const h = date.getHours();
  const i = date.getMinutes();

  const yyyy = y.toString();
  const mm = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : m.toString();
  const dd = d < 10 ? `0${d}` : d.toString();
  const hh = h < 10 ? `0${h}` : h.toString();
  const ii = i < 10 ? `0${i}` : i.toString();
  return `${yyyy}${mm}${dd} ${hh}:${ii}`;
}
```

Here's a link to a Repl where you can try it for yourself: https://repl.it/repls/TinyHopefulOrder

Answer (score 0):

[`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) gets you close to the format you want, and string manipulation can get you the rest of the way:

```js
const today = new Date();
const dateString = today.toISOString()
  .slice(0, -8)
  .replace(/-|T/g, match => match === 'T' ? ' ' : '');
console.log(dateString);
```

`Date.toISOString()` always returns a string of the form `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"` or `"±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"`. The [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) line removes `"-"`s and replaces `"T"` with `" "`, and [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) chops off the last 8 characters: the seconds, milliseconds, and timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to do this easily

```js
alert(moment().format("YYYYMMDD HH:mm"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
function clock() {
    function addZero(i) {
         if (i < 10) {
            return `0${i}`;
        } else {
            return `${i}`;
        }
    }
 
    const d = new Date();
    const time = `${addZero(d.getHours())}:${addZero(d.getMinutes())}:${addZero(d.getSeconds())}`;
     document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;
}
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="clock">test</p>
```